# Convert date string with a comma to valid Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

This is the data I have:

```
"Apr 02, 1990"
```

How can I convert this into a Datetime?

```
newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MMM-dd-yyyy", null),
```

gives me an unrecognized datetime exception

```
newDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

Does the same

If I strip the comma and attempt either, it is the same result.

Comment: `MMM-dd-yyyy` does not look like a format of your date, hence the exception. Try `MMM dd, yyyy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format doesn't match your date string use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Apr 02, 1990", "MMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null`.

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)